# PHP Push notification error in iphone?

Tags: php

I am getting the device to register, but I am not able to send the push. 
Is this a port issue I need to configure with my host?

Here is my full error messages:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home/content/w/i/s/wiseinmotion/html/appologie/admin/push/push_notify.php on line 90
Connection Failed - iPhone Push Notifications ServerConnection timed out
110

Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_close() in /home/content/w/i/s/wiseinmotion/html/appologie/admin/push/push_notify.php
```

Here is my code please, tell me where I put wrong step?

```
function pushMessage($deviceToken,$message,$app) {
    echo "Sending iPhone Push Notifications to " . $deviceToken . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Your Message: " . $message . "<br />";
    $time = time();
    $apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com'; 
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $apnsCert = './apns-iclean.pem';
    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
    if($apns) {
            $payload = array();
            $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
            $payload = json_encode($payload);
            $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
    } else { 
            echo "Connection Failed - iPhone Push Notifications Server";
            echo $errorString."<br />";
            echo $error."<br />";
    }
    //socket_close($apns);
    fclose($apns);
}
```

Please, guide me about this.

Thank You

Comment: The first one's pretty obvious - your system is not able to reach that host/port over at apple, and the connection's failing. That's what you have to work on... is that port firewalled somehow for you?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a function called `socket_close()` in the PHP file indicated in the fatal error message (`/home/content/w/i/s/wiseinmotion/html/appologie/admin/push/push_notify.php`). It's not defined, or you're not accessing it properly. Define that function or access it properly, and the error should go away.

Comment: k thanks for your response...i am using fclose($apns) i will get same result

Comment: Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home/content/w/i/s/wiseinmotion/html/appologie/admin/push/push_notify.php on line 90
Connection Failed - iPhone Push Notifications ServerConnection timed out
110

Comment: @516: That's telling you you cannot connect to the server.